# Testing for an empty list in FitNesse .Net

Tags: fitnesse

FitNesse .Net (using the FIT test system, not SLIM) supports testing for lists of the form:

```
element1, element2, ..., elementN
```

This works well. However, I can't figure out how to test for an *empty* list.

Empty strings can be tested for with `blank`. What's the equivalent for a list?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

|configure|processor|add operator|parsequotedstring|

|check|myemptylist|""|

Comment: I'll give it a try. But shouldn't FitNesse have the ability to check for empty lists in the same way it can check for nulls, etc., without any additional configuration? Your solution is very obscure :-)

Comment: Yes, a key word to indicate empty list would be a good enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here: https://github.com/imanushin/NetRunner/wiki/Collection-result

If there will be any collection on output NetRunner (and fitSharp) will write several red rows (e.g. test will fail).

For example, by using such functions I'm checking the error entries in the log: the expected entries count is empty list. However, any problematic row will be presented to me on the web page, which is very useful: I collects log results from the several files and story them in the test.